# Delete vote retraction logic is confusing

Tags: feature-request, status-review, user-experience, vote-to-delete

This has happened to me a couple of times: I vote to delete a question or an answer and move on. Later, I come across the same post forgetting that I have voted for its deletion before, so I vote again. The difference is that now clicking the same "Delete" link causes the vote retraction instead. Because the popup with the confirmation looks quite the same, except the text, I quickly click "Ok" and oops, my vote is irreversibly retracted.

Could it somehow be made more explicit that the existing deletion vote is mine, and that clicking the link retracts the vote? For example, with flags or closure votes that's made quite clear.

Comment: i mean, if you're not gonna read the notice anyway, what purpose would making it more explicit serve?

Comment: @KevinB the interaction flow may be different, like with the closure votes. The "OK" / "Cancel" popups are universally understood as "are you sure?", and since I clicked "Delete", I know (or I expect that I know) what I'm confirming. In my opinion, using both the same link title and a confirmation mechanism for opposite things is confusing.

Comment: @KevinB Having "Delete" and "Retract" on button instead of OK would be huge improvement.

Comment: Absolutely, or maybe a proper UI with a button like "Retract (you won't be able to vote again)" (and not the current confirm where pressing space - which I often do reflexively - will result in the action being taken)

Comment: Cross-site dupes (MSE): [Make the "delete" button different when you already voted to delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371810) and [Make the pop-up for retracting your delete vote different from the pop-up for casting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371331)

Comment: Just fix the d*** thing

Comment: Do you not also downvote the content you are trying to delete? That should serve as a visual cue that you've already visited it. If not, hovering over the delete option will tell you whether you've already voted or not via a tooltip. You should probably do *both* of these any time you think a post should be deleted. That being said, yes it would be nice for them to change the "Delete" link verbiage to "Retract" or something else (not "Undelete, because that's confusing with a deleted post you want to undelete).

Comment: I downvote and maybe delete. When I check the status of the downvotes later to see if the post has been improved I might vote to delete if it hasn't been improved and doesn't look likely that it ever will be. I might vote to delete if the questions gotten worse and isn't worth reverting. The presence of a downvote doesn't mean I've deleted, haven't deleted, or will or won't vote to delete at some point in the future.

Comment: Don't forget "Undelete" as well

Answer (score 29):

I agree this is a very bad bug that should be fixed as soon as possible.

The button is called "delete" regardless of whether one has already voted to delete or not. Humans are expecting a confirmation for such action to avoid accidental clicking. The UI should not be so misleading that clicking "delete" button will ask if one wants to retract the vote permanently. This is like pulling a trigger on the gun only to then realize the barrel is pointing back at the shooter.

The button needs to be renamed and the popup needs to be improved.

Comment: This. This. This. is one of this instances where there is an obvious problem, and yet ... sits forever while we get other UI updates we didn't ask for ...

Comment: @GhostCat There is a userscript that partially solves this. https://github.com/Spevacus/DeleteVoteRenameScript/raw/main/Delete%20Vote%20Rename.user.js

Comment: A user script isn't a fix but a **work around**. There is a significant difference between these two.But thanks for the link!

Comment: @Dharman Where do we stand with this? Every time I see *Delete (1)* I must double check whether the delete vote was mine or someone else's. Changing the delete link color, or adding a simple checkmark ✓ after the link when **I** have voted, or changing the link text to *Retract delete vote* would make it so much better in terms of UX.

Comment: @MrUpsidown It's still a bug.

Comment: I would rate this as 1000 times more urgent/important than the current voting buttons redesign... Was this FR even taken into account?