# Enhance close and delete links

Tags: feature-request, design, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

While we are currently running [A/B testing on button styling for vote arrows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-currently-in-a-b-testing), I am wondering whether the *Close* and *Delete* links on posts could also be enhanced in terms of UX.

Here is how the *Close* link looks when **I have voted** to close a question.

[image: Post action links]

And here is how it looks when **someone else has voted** to close the question, but not me.

[image: Post action links]

Yes, you are right, it's the same image. Because both look **exactly the same**.

Unless I wait for the tooltip to display — or click on the link — **I have no way to tell whether the close vote is mine, or not**.

The same goes for the *Delete* link when displayed.

**My main question/concern about it**: Should there not be a **visual difference** between when I have voted and when I have not?

Aside from that, should these links not be buttons since they are not taking you anywhere but rather let you do some *action* on the post you are viewing?

---

For reference, here are a few related requests:

- [Make the pop-up for retracting your delete vote different from the pop-up for casting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371331/280407)
- [Delete vote retraction logic is confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415362/1238965)
- [Indicate within questions that I already voted to close/reopen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326967/1238965)

Comment: "*Should these links not be buttons since they are not taking you anywhere but rather let you do some action on the post you are viewing?*" all the links under a post actions related to a post. None of the actions *lead* anywhere. Unless you don't have in-place edit and you try to edit, then you go to another page. But that's the only exception. Furthermore, inks being used for not-redirecting have been standard UX idiom on the web for decades.

Comment: @VLAZ Because something has been done in a certain way for decades doesn't necessarily mean it is good or best-practice. I am no UX expert, which is why I am not claiming it *needs* to be changed but rather turned this into a question. I suppose there must be some guidelines / best-practices on that topic.

Comment: Conversely, just because something is *different* doesn't make it better. Using pre-existing expectations that users are familiar with is generally preferred. Hence the decades of prior use I mentioned is relevant. Unless you're Microsoft or Apple or Facebook or otherwise large enough to afford to make up new concepts.

Comment: *Using pre-existing expectations that users are familiar with is generally preferred.* - this makes sense. But the main point of this feature request is to have a visual difference between when I have voted and when I have not — should these links remain links or become buttons.

Comment: "*a visual difference between when I have voted and when I have not — should these links remain links or become buttons*" I don't see the relation here. They can be distinguished visually in either case. Why should buttons be required for that? Here are just a few options: [normal](https://i.imgur.com/kFfauMc.png), [bold and red](https://i.imgur.com/gRHSY1s.png) (the style of an "undelete" button), [red background](https://i.imgur.com/TxcRVnE.png), [lower opacity](https://i.imgur.com/k26ne7S.png), [no underline](https://i.imgur.com/jBeJSYA.png) (applicable to high contrast mode only)

Comment: I think you got me wrong. What I am saying is that the most important part is that I can visually tell the difference between when I have voted and when I have not. Whether the links remain links or become buttons does not make any difference.

Comment: I completely agree that more clarity is needed. It's indeed a topic I wanted to tackle at some point using a userscript. It's literally in my backlog of userscript projects to do. However, I found the link to button point to be completely orthogonal to the rest of the FR.

Comment: @VLAZ I have reworded/clarified my question. Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: I feel in general tooltips are relied upon too heavily to explain functionality. It is possible to hover over the button to see if you’ve already voted to close or how many votes are needed to complete the action, etc. but this is counter intuitive, slow (due to the time it takes for the text to appear), and not mobile friendly.

Comment: Closing a FR as a duplicate of a 6 years old FR that has never been actioned. Okay. Sounds like it's a better option to focus on ruining the vote buttons.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Are you saying that it's not a duplicate of those questions? To me, it looks fairly clearly to be a duplicate of those, just combined into a single FR question. I could be wrong. I can also understand a significant level of frustration regarding this, and many other things, not being addressed.

Comment: BTW: for yourself, you can show an indication that you've voted to delete or close by adding the following CSS: `/* Indicate you've voted to close */ .js-post-menu button[title*="You"] .existing-flag-count:after, .js-post-menu button[title*="you"] .existing-flag-count:after { content:")*";} /* Indicate you've voted to delete */ .js-post-menu button.js-delete-post[title*="You"]:after, .js-post-menu button.js-delete-post[title*="you"]:after { content:"*"; position: relative; right:.3em; }`

Comment: I am saying it is not a duplicate of the 2nd question you marked as a duplicate. It is indeed a duplicate of the 1st one but it is 6 years old and indeed it is frustrating to see feature requests that gather quite much interest just left aside while you are trying to enforce unwanted UI changes at the same time. But never mind...

Comment: *Please* don't lump moderators in with SE wrt. anything regarding what changes happen with the site's UI (unless you find explicit statements from a specific moderator). Moderators have only *slightly* more access to communicating with employees with respect to discussing such changes. We *certainly* don't have the ability to dictate that changes will or won't happen with the site's UI. Many/most (all???) of us substantially disagree with some, if not many/most, of the recent UI changes (actual/proposed/being investigated). Many of those changes have made our moderating ***much*** harder.

Comment: I am not. But you are right, I should not have said *you* but rather *SE employees* in my last comment. This FR was getting some interest and you (this time it is *you*) just closed it in favor of a 6 years old FR that nobody seems to have cared about for quite some time. As I said, never mind, I'll live with it.

Comment: @MrUpsidown have a look at [How to renew an old feature request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364131/how-to-renew-an-old-feature-request)